# Docker swap support in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cgroup

It seems like Ubuntu 18.04 broke docker swap support.

It's working fine in ubuntu 16.04, but this morning when I setup a new server with ubuntu 18.04 it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to enable swap accounting in docker, with ubuntu 18.04?

My docker info:

```
root@proxima:~# docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: btrfs
 Build Version: Btrfs v4.15.1
 Library Version: 102
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-20-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.33GiB
Name: proxima
ID: HFCK:DE5O:VDGY:PK3Z:WXNP:OF4P:CGIV:Z3XE:TM7F:VIMG:7ZUH:CXNW
Docker Root Dir: /ozone/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

my etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard   0   1
/dev/md1    /boot   ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard   0   1
/dev/sda3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sda4       /ozone  btrfs   defaults,noatime,ssd,compress=zstd,commit=120       0       0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
```

Comment: By default 18.04 uses a swap file, not a dedicated partition.

Comment: that's just how my provider configured the system. I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to edit files in `/etc/default/grub.d/` instead of editing the file `/etc/default/grub` .

Dunno why they changed it.